# VMware Workstation not running after performing an update on Ubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: 14.04, vmware-workstation

After performing a **kernel update** through Software Updater, **VMWare Workstation** showing me this and not starting up. I tried reinstalling but that did not work. My current kernel is 4.4.0-38-generic and my OS is 64 bit.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Last lines of this file:

Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-1fsTIT/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.4.0-38-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2016-10-12T13:02:22.194+06:00| vthread-4| 
 W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.

I know there exists similar questions. I tried  but they did not solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my issue is solved. It was so silly. My VMWare Workstation 12.0.0 is not compatible with the linux kernel version. I downloaded the latest version 12.5.0, installed it and now it is working fine.